# Problem with GRUB, can't boot in any OS

Tags: boot, grub2

Im dual booting Ubuntu and Windows 7 anyway a couple of days ago i was editing the grub  to enable the graphical interface for backtrack, anyway I screwed up the grub accidentally, now I can't load neither of the systems because of the 'Minimal bash-like' screen. Is there a way I could delete Ubuntu to boot in windows 7? Or how could I fix this since I need to boot in win7 urgently.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try Ubuntu [boot repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)? It is the easiest method to fix grub issues. The automatic fix usually does a very good job. All the instructions you need are in the linked page. I believe it also comes bundled in with Ubuntu 12.10 live CD.